# I keep on getting pubsepc.yaml error when running flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**This is my pubsepc.yaml code**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart: ^0.27.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.0+3
  pendatic: ^1.8.0

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  dev_dependencies:
    flutter_test:
      sdk: flutter

  flutter:
     uses-material-design: true

     To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
     assets:
       - assets/images/apple-in-hand.jpg
       - assets/images/apricots.jpg
       - assets/images/asparagus.jpg
```

**The error message I keep on getting is like below**

```
PS C:\Users\Geon-Young.Hong\e_commerce> flutter packages get
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Unexpected child "To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this" found under "flutter".
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Users\Geon-Young.Hong\e_commerce\pubspec.yaml
```

**There is no issue found when I run flutter doctor**

```
PS C:\Users\Geon-Young.Hong\e_commerce> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.57.0)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
```

**This is flutter & dart version info**

```
Flutter 2.0.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b1395592de (2 months ago) • 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
Engine • revision 2dce47073a
Tools • Dart 2.12.2
```

I cannot import rxdart, image_picker package. (There is an assets directory outside of lib)
it could be a version-related issue or something else.

[image]

Is there anybody who can help me out with this matter?

Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the section `To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:` from the `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

The error its telling you that there is an unexpected child, `"To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:"` that line should not be there, comment it out, or delete it ang `pub get` should run fine

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code to your **pubsepc.yaml** all my code bellow.

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart: ^0.27.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.0+3
  pendatic: ^1.8.0

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
    
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/apple-in-hand.jpg
    - assets/images/apricots.jpg
    - assets/images/asparagus.jpg
```